# How to return login value to database on custom ISL for Micros Simphony?

Tags: sql-server, pos, isl

We are running Micros Simphony 2 and Micros can't support the use of our own employee cards because of a leading 0 which database cannot handle... I put myself in search of developing custom ISL file which would trim the 0 before login the employee in. I managed successfully to do so with some test.

```
var auth_code       : A40  //Declare global variable
event inq : 1
Input auth_code{ M2,1,3,4 }, "Enter authorization code" //State that the infos are on track 2 (M2) field 1 start on character 3 and is 4 digits long
endevent
```

So this code above does the job but doesn't make any call to database to compare the login. So I tried to implement a macro that call for Micros Login function as first step then Wait for Input as second step and then Sim Inquire that call my code as third step however when swiping the card the value is returned straight away to the database. I tried also to make a macro starting for the wait for input then put my function it wouldn't work.

Since any swipe on the Home screen sign you in I was thinking of putting in place my own Sign In. Is there any way to open a connection to the SQL Server database and create maybe my own "Sign In" function?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You appear to reference Oracle and SQL Server interchangibly here. Oracle and SQL Server are completely different RDBMS.

Comment: Sorry I should have said Micros Login Function to not confuse everybody I am talking about the POS system Sign In native function. Will Edit it now.